# jQuery .index among an object collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, indexing

I need to find an element's index among other elements matching a given selector. I can't simply use .index() without arguments are i need to ignore several "foreign" elements.

```
$('body').delegate('.TabHeader', 'click', function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        // All tab headers.
        $headers = $this.parent().children('.TabHeader'),
        // All tab contents.
        $contents = $this.parent().siblings('.TabContent'),
        // New active tab position.
        // PROBLEM HERE, i would like to do that, but jQuery doesn't handle it:
        index = $this.index( $headers ),
        // New active tab header.
        $newActiveHeader = $headers.eq( index ),
        // New active tab content.
        $newActiveContent = $contents.eq( index );

    // Hidding all other tabs.
    $headers.not( $newActiveHeader ).removeClass('Active');
    $contents.not( $newActiveContent ).removeClass('Active').addClass('Hidden');

    // Showing new active tab.
    $newActiveHeader.addClass('Active');
    $newActiveContent.addClass('Active').removeClass('Hidden');

});
```

With an HTML code of that kind :

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="TabHeader Active">Tab 0</li>
        <li class="TabHeader">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="TabHeader">Tab 2</li>
        <!-- There can be foreign elements mixed with <li> elements -->
    </ul>
    <div class="TabContent Active">
        Content 0
    </div>
    <div class="TabContent Hidden">
        Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="TabContent Hidden">
        Content 2
    </div>
    <!-- There can be foreign elements mixed with <div> elements -->
</div>
```

(Tabs are dynamically generated, so i'm using .delegate() if it matters)

Is there a clear way to get the index of an element **among a matched set of elements** and not just among the children of the parent ?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery index method will return the index of the passed element within a collection:

```
// Assuming `this` refers to a `.TabHeader` element
var i = $('.TabHeader').index(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I actually just figured it out : `index = $headers.index( $this ),`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this.index(); // you don't have to refer to it's parent or siblings!
```

This will do.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/9QwNu/)